# iText: generate PDF from ANY file(including .java, .xml, .php) and keep formatting

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am currently trying to create an application that converts any font code from a software project into a PDF. I'm using iText to generate the PDF but I can't keep the tabbing of the file.
Here's the method that reads the files(simple bufferedReader, but I get every read line and put it in a linkedList):

```
public static LinkedList<String> lerArquivoQualquerDeTexto(String URL) {
    LinkedList<String> textoLido = new LinkedList<String>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(URL)))
    {

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            textoLido.add(sCurrentLine + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return textoLido;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } 


}
```

And here's the iText convertion of this LinkedList i just read using BufferedReader:

```
 private static String FILE = "c:/temp/FirstPdf.pdf";
  private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
      Font.BOLD);
  private static Font redFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9,
      Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
  private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16,
      Font.BOLD);
  private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
      Font.BOLD);
  private static Font smallFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9,
          Font.NORMAL);

  /**
   * gera o PDF de UM único arquivo já lido 
   * @param textoLido texto lido pelo buffer
   * @param nomeDoArquivoLido nome do arquivo lido, já obtido pelo LeitorArquivoTexto.java
   * @return
   */
public static boolean gerarPDFDeString(LinkedList<String> textoLido, String nomeDoArquivoLido)
{
     try {
          Document document = new Document();
          PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
          document.open();
          addMetaData(document);
          addTitlePage(document);
          addContent(document, textoLido, nomeDoArquivoLido);
          document.close();
          return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return false;
        }
}

 // iText allows to add metadata to the PDF which can be viewed in your Adobe
  // Reader
  // under File -> Properties
  private static void addMetaData(Document document) {
    document.addTitle("My first project to register");
    document.addSubject("Using iText");
    document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
    document.addAuthor("Lars Vogel");
    document.addCreator("Lars Vogel");
  }

  private static void addTitlePage(Document document)
      throws DocumentException {
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    // We add one empty line
    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    // Lets write a big header
    preface.add(new Paragraph("Nome Do Projeto", redFont));

    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    // Will create: Report generated by: _name, _date
    preface.add(new Paragraph("Report generated by: " + System.getProperty("user.name") + ", " + new Date(), //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
        smallBold));
    addEmptyLine(preface, 3);


    document.add(preface);
    // Start a new page
    document.newPage();
  }

  private static void addContent(Document document, LinkedList<String> textoArquivoLido, String nomeDoArquivoLido) throws DocumentException {
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor(nomeDoArquivoLido, redFont);
    anchor.setName(nomeDoArquivoLido);

    // Second parameter is the number of the chapter
    Chapter catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < textoArquivoLido.size(); i++)
    {
        String umaLinhaLida = textoArquivoLido.get(i);
        Phrase umaLinhaDoPdf = new Phrase(umaLinhaLida, smallFont);
        catPart.add(umaLinhaDoPdf);
    }






    // now add all this to the document
    document.add(catPart);


  }
```

I'm trying to convert a .java file from my java project, but the problem is: my output file(the .pdf file) keeps being written without any of my formatting tabs! Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `/t` in PDF, so you need to make sure to use spaces instead of tabs. Furthermore you are using Times_Roman: this is a proportional font. Proportional fonts don't preserve formatting, you need to use a mono-spaced font such as Courier.

Comment: I got the suggestion of using Courier, but for the "/t" problem, are you suggesting that I replace all "/t" of the strings I read in the BufferedReader to a "      "(something like this)?

Comment: @Fabio use four or five spaces - "    "

Comment: Actually, you need to (1) decide how much spaces a single tab can be at max, then (2) count your (monospaced!) characters and insert as many spaces as necessary to jump the *next* tab distance. It's possible as well with a proportional font, but then you'd have to count in character width units, which is a lot more work. (Not really a *lot* - it's basically the same -, but difficult enough for a mere beginner.)